# Rendered Head Element Missing for Custom URL (React/NextJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, head

For the life of me I can't get my  element to render properly in production with a custom URL. However, when I use the production url for heroku all meta values and titles are as they should be. What could I be missing on the backend for this custom URL to behave like the heroku (production) url?

FWIW I've tried using NextJS's  (big H) element in just _document.js, then just in the individual pages, then in both and none of that worked. I tried then the regular  element in all of those places and still nothing worked.

Stack (relavant parts):

- Node/Next
- Herokuapp
- Custom URL setup in Namecheap

This is what is desired (as seen in Heroku url production)

```html
<head>
<title>Title goes here</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900|Lora:400,700|Raleway:300,400,500|Mrs+Saint+Delafield|Oswald:400,500,600,700|Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
<meta name="google" value="notranslate"><meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="next-head-count" content="2">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/BQtb3SsHNlDBZ0GR5XO8e/pages/_app.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/BQtb3SsHNlDBZ0GR5XO8e/pages/index.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/runtime/webpack-c212667a5f965e81e004.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/framework.e3dc35540e5154efbe26.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/commons.7b2560adb4b087ff3b88.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/runtime/main-6515f3f5795ff732ae00.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/f11626d17d809f516e30bfc87982fa419b7b3742.823cc49f4a5a17b08bcf.js" as="script">
<style data-styled="active" data-styled-version="5.0.1"></style>
<link href="/_next/static/BQtb3SsHNlDBZ0GR5XO8e/pages/about.js" rel="prefetch" as="script">
<link href="/_next/static/chunks/f11626d17d809f516e30bfc87982fa419b7b3742.823cc49f4a5a17b08bcf.js" rel="prefetch" as="script">
</head>
```

This is what is wrong when viewed with my custom url although it's hitting the same server.

```html
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="KEYWORDS" content="">
        <meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="">
        <meta name="VERSION" content="">
        <link href="" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <title></title>
    </head>
...
```

The correct behavior followed by the incorrect.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder

Comment: So the problem is that the `frameset` and its `frame` are missing? (Side note: [`frameset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset) and `frame` are deprecated.)

Comment: I re-read the question and It appears to me that you are expecting the contents of the `frameset` and `frame` to be expanded without those elements whereas you are seeing those nested inside those elements. 
Is this correct? If yes:

These elements have nothing to do with `nextjs` and would be output exactly as you specified as a feature of HTML. 

If you can provide the confirmation of this expectation we can troubleshoot further.

Comment: Apologies. I copied and pasted incorrectly the code snippets. I've suffered a wildfire recently and my community is devastated with homes lost. I'm not currently at my sharpest. I don't mean to waste time and am thankful for your help thus far.

The problem is the <head> element doesn't render properly ie all the meta tags are missing along with even the title. when I open the page via my custom URL but not if I use the herokuapp production url.

Comment: I'm going to inject the meta tag via vanilla js for now. Horrible work around and sort this out in time. fwiw. ugh.